# Execute a SQL command within a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, stored-procedures, execute

I want to execute an SQL command inside a stored procedure and then execute the stored procedure (in SQL Server):

```
CREATE PROC ps_getPerson
    @id INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX);

    SET @query = ' SELECT * FROM Person WHERE id='+@id

    EXEC @query
END
```

and execute it outside

```
EXEC ps_getPerson @id = 1
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: What is the point of the dynamic sql here? From what you posted it is just a layer of complexity that provides no benefit. BTW, if you do something like this you should sp_executesql so you can pass in parameters. The pattern you are starting here is dangerous because it is potentially opening up your code to sql injection.

Comment: This is not the real command just for showing you my problem the real one had more tests cases etc my problem is to execute the proc

Comment: But you posted a code example that will execute it just fine. What is your question here?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a learning experiment with Dynamic SQL.

1st, you are tring to concat a string with an int.
2nd, you are calling the SP without the proper syntax

```
CREATE PROC ps_getPerson
    @id int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX);
    SET @query = ' SELECT * FROM Person WHERE id='+cast(@id as varchar(50))
EXEC @query
END
```

**To Exec**

```
EXEC ps_getPerson 1
```

Comment: Or better yet, use sp_executesql and parameterize @id. :)

Comment: @SeanLange Agreed. I was thinking "What About Bob?"

Comment: Assuming it's a learning experiment with Dynamic SQL, it's been asked and answered a few hundred times.

Answer (score 0):

I really am not sure why you are doing dynamic SQL inside your proc. Running a normal select should be just fine unless you have specific requirements. Also, replace the * with an explicit list of field names.

```
CREATE PROC ps_getPerson
    @id int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM Person 
    WHERE id=@id

END
```